# How to force the UDP/TCP network packet to take the pre-decided Nexthop?

Tags: networking, load

I have a Client issuing a request to server S. Assume UDP/TCP request. `HOP1` is a load balancer switch and assume it has detected that path `HOP4->HOP5` is better to route the packet to `ServerS`. My Question is , After `HOP1` has received the pkt generated by client, how can it force the packet to take the best path as calculated to reach S i.e. via HOP4 only.

```
CL -------HOP1---------HOP2-------HOP3--------ServerS
          |                                   |
          |-----------HOP4-----HOP5-----------|
```

I was thinking, that HOP1 should set the field SA,DA, MAC-SA, MAC-DA fields of the pkt as follows :

```
SA : HOP1
DA : ServerS
SMAC - HOP1MAC
DMAC - HOP4MAC
```

Would that work ? Is there any better approach ?

My Other doubt is that, for `Server S`, `HOP4` would appear as CLient since it forwarded the client request impersonating as client to Server S. So, `HOP4` would receive the reply from `Server S`. How `HOP4` can determine that the reply it has received is actually for the CLient CL and not for itself ? Does NAT comes into picture ? Can somebody shed some light ?

Answer (score 1):

IP has a source routing option, but no network engineer worth his pay configures routers to allow source routing. Network routing needs to be deterministic, and the routing protocols will determine which direction packets should go. Allowing an end-device or application to do that breaks this.

MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, and the layer-2 frames are stripped off the layer-3 packets and discarded at each hop. A new layer-2 frame is created for each hop in the path, and it is stripped off and discarded at the net hop. MAC addresses are only local to a LAN, and they do not survive across a router hop. Using a destination MAC address that is not local to the source LAN will guarantee failure. In fact, not all layer-2 protocols use MAC addresses, and you have no way to know if any of the links between the hops do are don't use MAC addresses. Of the layer-2 protocols that do use MAC addresses, some use 48-bit MAC addresses, and some use 64-bit MAC addresses.

There really is no way an application or host can guarantee the path that packets will take. That is a job for the routers.

Comment: What I am trying to tell you is that, in almost all cases, routers will ignore any IP source routing. Also, your first router will never receive the frame from the host if the destination MAC address is on a different LAN. Layer-2 addresses, including MAC addresses, are only relevant, or ever seen on a LAN, and LAN traffic is sent to the host on the LAN with the destination MAC address. If the destination MAC address is on a different LAN, no host on the source LAN, including the router, will get the frames with that destination MAC address.

Comment: Layer-2 addresses deliver frames on a LAN, and layer-3 addresses deliver frames between LANs.

Answer (score 0):

I think after gaining some more wisdom in the field of networking, I got the answer to this Question.
`Source packet routing (SPRING)` is the new buzz in networking to achieve it.
Other techniques is `Tunneling` - `Ip in IP encapsulation`, `GRE tunnels` etc.

Comment: Most routers will ignore source routing. It is a really bad idea to let a host dictate how packets are routed. This disrupts the carefully designed network, and it kills the IP routing idea of dynamic routing that automatically reroutes around damage.